# Calculate number of fields

Tags: sql, cross-reference

I have three tables:

- Article(idArticle,NameArt)
- Tag(idTag, NameTag)
- ArtiTag(idArticle,idTag)

I want to have a result like this: NameTag,Count(Articles that belongs to that tag)

I tried the following:

```
SELECT Tag.NameTag , COUNT(DISTINCT(idArticle))
  FROM ArtiTag, ArtiTag
```

but it returns always only one row, even if I have many tags and many articles related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t.NameTag, COUNT(*)
    FROM ArtiTag at
        INNER JOIN Tag t
            ON at.idTag = t.idTag
    GROUP BY t.NameTag;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select T.idTag, Max(nametag), count(artitag.idArticle) from Tag t 
  left join ArtiTag on t.idTag=ArtiTag.idTag
    Group by t.idTag
```

This query outputs all tags including also tags with 0 articles.

Comment: Thanks; The following fix the case where some tags have 0 articles Select Distinct(ArtiTag.idTag), nametag, count(artitag.idArticle) from Tag t left join ArtiTag on t.idTag=ArtiTag.idTag  WHERE ArtiTag.idTag IS NOT NULL Group By t.idTag;

Comment: Select NameTag, COUNT(ArtiTag.idArticle) from Tag t left join ArtiTag on t.idTag=ArtiTag.idTag  WHERE ArtiTag.idTag IS NOT NULL Group By t.NameTag